# Is gcroot and /clr mixed mode and a C++ wrapper the shortest path from pure C to C#?

Tags: c#, c, clr

So I am writing a plug-in DLL which is pure C (and a heap of foreign includes), but most of the real code is in an existing C# class library. I'm looking for the shortest path from C (not C++) to C#. The foreign includes are not C++ safe.

There are heaps of samples around for C++, not much for pure C.

It seems I should be able to compile the whole DLL as /clr but compile the C as not; then include in the same DLL a C++ wrapper that presents a C API but contains managed code to call the C# class.

So instantiate the C# class and hang onto it in a gcroot in a C++ class, and pass the C++ class pointer as a void* back for the the C code to keep for future calls.

Quite a few details to get right, but not all that much code. Is there a better way?

---

Thought it was time to add a bit of code.

```
// Wrapper.h
#pragma once
// API for call by C
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void* wrap_create();
    void wrap_doit(void* wrapper, char* input, char* output, int maxlen);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// Wrapper.cpp

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vcclr.h>
#include "Wrapper.h"
using namespace System;

class Wrapper {
public:
    gcroot<Wrappee::Evaluator^> eval;
    Wrapper() {}
};

void* wrap_create() {
    Wrapper* w = new Wrapper();
    w->eval = gcnew Wrappee::Evaluator();
    return w;
}

void wrap_doit(void* wrapper, char* input, char* output, int maxlen) {
    Wrapper* w = (Wrapper*)wrapper;
    String^ s = w->eval->Doit(gcnew String(input));
    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(s);
    wcstombs(output, wch, maxlen);
}

// Wrappee.cs
using System;
namespace Wrappee {
  public class Evaluator {
    string _s;
    public static Evaluator Create() {
      return new Evaluator {
        _s = "wrapped evaluator"
      };
    }

    public string Doit(string s) {
      return _s + ":" + s;
    }
  }
}
```

Why wouldn't that work? The code is based on this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/481fa11f%28v=VS.140,d=hv.2%29.aspx.

---

Comment: Direct PInvoke of native code may be easier if C library interface is simple.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: First thing I thought of. But the C code is frighteningly complex, full of macros, bit masks, global variables. Absolutely no chance.

Comment: You need to scratch the idea that this is going to be easy.  This is "reverse pinvoke", native code that calls C# code needs to deal with the detail that the CLR needs to be loaded and initialized.  And most importantly, that a managed exception is diagnosable and does not crash the plugin host.  Only COM can do this job correctly.  Either by writing an adapter in C# that uses [ComVisible(true)] or by using the custom CLR hosting interfaces, ICLRMetaHost is the core one.  It googles well.

Comment: @HansPassant: based on your long record of answering these questions, I believe you and I will follow that lead. I still can't see why it wouldn't work. The MSDN topic "Using C++ Interop (Implicit PInvoke)" suggests it should. [Did I mention I really am not a COM fan?]

Comment: Pretty important to understand the difference between pinvoke and "reverse pinvoke".  Managed code calling native code is easy and very well supported.  Especially in C++/CLI as that article tells you.  The problem is that your plugin host is not managed code.  You don't have a C# class trying to call your native code, you are doing it the opposite way.  It is certainly possible, just not easy.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for the hints. I wrote up an answer, but didn't accept it. Feel free to edit, or write your own if you need some points.

Comment: It's fine, I already upvoted it, go ahead and close your question by accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, that won't work. The managed class depends on the CLR runtime, which needs to be hosted by the application. For a managed app that happens automatically (`mscoree.dll` during startup), but for a native app there is no host so no CLR.

So we have to provide one. As @hanspassant helpfully pointed out, this is "Reverse P/Invoke" and it really is different. You have to get there by the COM hosting interfaces, specifically `ICLRMetaHost`.

And the good news is that there is a sample here to show how it's done: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0.

There are other samples too: search for `CppHostCLR`.